# Mysql Update using limit

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, limit

I have this code

```
$sql="select * from wifi where status!='off' limit 0, $limit";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$i=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $i.") ".$row["user"]." - ".$row["password"]."<br/>";
$i++;
}
```

Now I'd like to update the row that result from my output with the status=off

I'm trying to use

```
$sql="Update wifi Set staus='off' limit 0,6"
```

But It doesn't work

Comment: Don't use a start offset, just a limit number: `sql="Update wifi Set staus='off' limit 6"` [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="Update wifi Set staus='off' WHERE id IN (
select id from wifi where status!='off' limit 0, $limit
)"
```

Correct your `id` field with respective name.

Answer (score 0):

Spell of status is incorrect as well as just limit number.

```
$sql="Update wifi Set status='off' limit 6"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
UPDATE wifi SET staus='off'
  WHERE id IN (
         SELECT id FROM wifi LIMIT 0, 6
     ) temp
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `where` condition:

```
Update wifi
    Set status = 'off'
    where status <> 'off'
    limit 0, 6;
```

However, this is not guaranteed to update the same rows returned by the `select`.  SQL does not guarantee that running the same query twice returns the same rows -- unless you use an `ORDER BY`.  So, both queries should have an `ORDER BY` before the `LIMIT`.

In addition, you should stop using mysql_ functions and switch to mysqli_.